# Manipulating NSDictionary data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've managed to export the below data, multiplied by several hundred, into an NSDictionary. I now need to build out a way to put this data into Tinder style app. Can anyone advise how I can get my app to pull out the data against Key "Title" for various indexes. Currently it pulls out 45 records of data containing that one Title as there are 45 keys in my data set.

```
    {

    AttachmentFiles =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/AttachmentFiles";

        };

    };

    Attachments = 0;

    AuthorId = 22;

    AverageRating = "<null>";

    BestAnswerId = "<null>";

    Body = "We need to think xyz";

    CategoriesLookupId = 16;

    Community = "<null>";

    ContentType =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/ContentType";

        };

    };

    ContentTypeId = 0x01200200C5BB1FEE2601B9439CD527C288D85A7B;

    Created = "2014-03-21T08:37:33Z";

    DescendantLikesCount = 8;

    DescendantRatingsCount = "<null>";

    DiscussionLastUpdated = "2014-06-19T12:57:58Z";

    EditorId = 96;

    EmailSender = "<null>";

    FieldValuesAsHtml =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/FieldValuesAsHtml";

        };

    };

    FieldValuesAsText =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/FieldValuesAsText";

        };

    };

    FieldValuesForEdit =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/FieldValuesForEdit";

        };

    };

    File =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/File";

        };

    };

    FileSystemObjectType = 1;

    FilterCategory = "<null>";

    FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject";

        };

    };

    Folder =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/Folder";

        };

    };

    GUID = "28144fd4-84b0-434b-9e99-01d939e6a773";

    Has20likes = "<null>";

    ID = 3;

    Id = 3;

    IsFeatured = 0;

    IsIdeaCreated = "<null>";

    IsQuestion = 0;

    LastReplyById = 49;

    LikesCount = 5;

    MemberLookupId = 7;

    Modified = "2015-03-11T15:25:20Z";

    "OData__UIVersionString" = "2.0";

    ParentItemEditorId = "<null>";

    ParentItemID = "<null>";

    ParentList =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/ParentList";

        };

    };

    Popularity = "7.23632608186099";

    RatingCount = "<null>";

    RoleAssignments =         {

        "__deferred" =             {

            uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)/RoleAssignments";

        };

    };

    StepChangePillar = "<null>";

    Title = "JIRA Governance";

    "__metadata" =         {

        etag = "\"14\"";

        id = "Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)";

        type = "SP.Data.Community_x0020_DiscussionListItem";

        uri = "https://xxxxxxx/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1594ea5e-0ca7-4de3-81aa-4082bde336a4')/Items(3)";

    };

},
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a clue what you are talking about. Please can you clarify what you mean and also share some code so we can see what you have attempted already to resolve your own issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array of dictionaries correct?

If so this should work:

```
NSInteger index = 0; //You can set this to the current page of your scroll view
NSArray * items = /* YOUR ARRAY OF DICTIONARIES */;
NSDictionary * dict = [items objectAtIndex:index];
NSString * title = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

You might also consider making a subclass of NSObject and building in a parser for your dictionary so you can access the variables with strong types.